# Ubuntu and Windows 8.1 dual boot problem

Tags: dual-boot, 14.04, windows, windows-8

I have Asus X550C laptop which came with FreeDOS on it.
I installed Windows 8.1 on it and then Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Then when I rebooted the system only Ubuntu was booting up. I updated grub using sudo update-grub command and it found the Windows and everything was running smoothly.

But after a month I had to repair Ubuntu because of some issues. I booted with a boot-able USB and chose to repair the existing installation of Ubuntu. This time I can't locate Windows 8 for the life of me. I edited the grub file to show at start-up. Edited the grub file to add menu entry. But nothing.

Please help me boot windows as I have my life's work on that.

```
sudo parted -l

Model: ATA WDC WD5000LPVX-8 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt

Number  Start   End    Size    File system     Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB  537MB   fat32                 boot
 2      538MB   496GB  495GB   ext4
 3      496GB   500GB  4174MB  linux-swap(v1)
```

Comment: When you say repair, do you mean a reinstall? There is a bug where a reinstall means overwrite entire hard drive. Post this to see partitions: sudo parted -l

Comment: added the result of sudo parted -l

Comment: That is only 3 partitions, UEFI boot, Ubuntu & swap. No Windows NTFS partitions. STOP using system. Use only live installer or other live DVD or flash drive. You will not be able to recover Windows, but may be able to recover some data. Best option was with any dual boot system to have good backups. First try testdisk, then photorec, but many with NTFS suggest GetDataBack, but that is not free, although to you see if it recovers more before buying.

Comment: My heart is bleeding now. What to do? Everything was on windows.... my ebooks, movies, programs, MATLAB etc.....

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you recover data, but always use the Something Else option when re/installing in a dual-boot environment.

Comment: my noobness will kill me someday..... :'(

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery And: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk  And this which is very slow: http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/PhotoRec OR: http://www.getdata.com/

Answer (score -1):

Im no expert as i am only young but have you checked that your bios is set to boot ubuntu as default if not check it by pressing the del key when you see the asus logo and go across to boot in the bios options from here you should be able to view the priorities and enable or disable them, check windows is enabled then make it priority.

Comment: Fixing whatever dual-boot issues won't help, because OP's Windows installation is already gone according to the output of `parted`. There's nothing left to dual-boot.